# Ionic autocomplete component with large datasets

Tags: ionic2

I'm experimenting Ionic with it's new grid layout on a new desktop app.

For this I need an autocomplete component with a datasource ( REST ) with more than 10.000 records.

Currently I'm trying ionic2-autocomplete but it have some bugs.

Does anyone have experienced this component or some other for this pourpose ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed ionic2-autocomplete with the ng-select component.

Works ok with multiselect and autocomplete features.

https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select